How to Handle Unused S3 Objects in a CMS?
I have a Content Management System (CMS) where users can upload images or videos. As soon as a user adds media to the editor, it gets uploaded to an S3 bucket, and the object key is returned and saved in the database.
However, there are two scenarios where S3 objects remain in the bucket but are no longer needed:

Unpublished Articles: If a user doesn't save the article, the media is uploaded to the S3 bucket, but its key will never be stored in the database.

Deleted Content: If an article or a media element within an article is deleted, the corresponding S3 object will remain in the bucket, but its key will be removed from the database.


I opted for the solution of immediately uploading images or videos because it reduces the wait time for the user when there are multiple media elements to save.
Currently, I'm implementing a cron job in my backend that regularly checks for S3 objects that do not belong to any article. The job then deletes these unused objects.
The reason I don't delete the objects immediately after an article is unsaved or deleted is to avoid making the user wait for multiple requests. Also, handling deletions in a cron job centralizes the logic, making the implementation simpler and less error-prone.
Is using a cron job to clean up unused S3 objects the right solution for this problem? Is there a better approach or a best practice recommended by AWS for handling such scenarios?

Your approach of using a cron job to clean up unused S3 objects addresses the main objective, but Regular scans of the entire S3 bucket and database could become resource-intensive as data grows
I will approach it differently by Implementing a tagging system for S3 objects. When an object is associated with an article, tag it as "in-use". Use S3 Lifecycle rules or your cron job to delete untagged objects after a certain period. This will provide more context about object usage and can be combined with S3 Lifecycle rules for efficient cleanup
Example Lifecycle Rule:
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "ID": "Delete untagged objects",
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "Filter": {
        "And": {
          "Prefix": "uploads/",
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Status",
              "Value": "in-use"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
        "NoncurrentDays": 1
      },
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 7
      }
    }
  ]
}

Using lifecycle rules will remove your cron job. Although you can do the same using cronjob if you need more control.

Thanks for the suggestion! However, tagging objects as "in-use" still requires handling deletions and updates in real-time. My cron job approach centralizes the cleanup and avoids issues if a user closes their browser mid-process. Do you have an idea how to handle this problem properly?

You will always have some point when a user says, yes it is uploaded/confirmed for use. This will be when a record is created in your DB. All you have to do is, add in-use as and when record is created in db on S3 Object. Then rest of the process can be automated with lifecycle management rules.

I get what you wanna do with setting the "in-use". But the my problem is, the removing of the "in-use" tag which has to be done on real time. And there I have the problem with edge cases like closing the browser.

Do it other way around. apply the tag once Db record is created. When initially the S3 object is uploaded, don't apply in-use tag. Once the record is uploaded and confirmed saved in your DB, then apply the in-use tag. When the key is deleted in DB, then remove the in-use tag.
